# NextJS + Typescript, How to handle "Element implicitly has an 'any' type" with getStaticProps?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to make a "blog" type site.

Here's how i fetch my posts (I'm just using the NextJS tutorial) :

**Post.js**

```js
const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'pages/articles')

function getSortedPostsData() {
    // Get File Name
    const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)
    const allPostsData = fileNames.map(fileName => {
        // remove the .md
        const id = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '')

        // Read md files
        const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, fileName)
        const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')

        // Use gray-matter to parse md files
        const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

        // Combine the data with the id
        return {
            id,
            ...matterResult.data
        }
    })
    return allPostsData.sort(({date: a}, {date: b}) => {
        if(a < b) {
            return 1
        } else if (a > b) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    })
}
```

Here's how I try to retrieve datas using typescript

```js
type LayoutProps = {
    article: Boolean;
}
interface ArticleProps {
    article: LayoutProps
    allPostsData: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const allPostsData = getSortedPostsData()
    return {
        props: {
            allPostsData
        }
    }
}

const Articles: NextPage<ArticleProps> = ({article, allPostsData}) => {
    return(
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Articles</title>
                <link
                    rel="preload"
                    href="fonts/OhnoFatfaceDemo-12Pt.otf"
                    as="font"
                    crossOrigin=""
                />
                <meta name="description" content="XXXX" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
            </Head>
            <BarbaHeader/>
            <h3 className='h3Title'>Nos articles</h3>
            <LayoutContent article={true}>
            {allPostsData.map(({ id, date, title}) => (
                <ArticleCards key={id} title={title} date={date}/>
            ))}
            </LayoutContent>
            <BarbaFooter/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Articles
```

Here's where i'm having an issues :

```js
{allPostsData.map(({ id, date, title}) => (
    <ArticleCards key={id} title={title} date={date}/>
))}
```

I'm having the "Binding element 'id, date, title' implicitly has an 'any'" issues

I'm trying to give it a type but I think i'm giving it in the wrong way cuz it didn't worked and my elements stayed with a "any" type

Comment: not sure but seems there are several errors. First of all, in your `ArticleProps` interface, I would say that  `allPostsData` type is `ReturnType<typeof getSortedPostsData>` . If the return type of your function is known, better to use it, do you have the signature of the Posts ? Then I you type also `GetStaticProps` something like `GetStaticProps<{allPostsData:ReturnType<typeof getSortedPostsData>}>`

Comment: In addition to what @Jerome said, I'd also start by properly typing the `getSortedPostsData` function, and continue from there.

Comment: Thanks you guys ! It's working now !